# Cause of failure/Bad record in transaction

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have a source table **DUMPTABLE** in **stage1** which contains millions of records. I want to process those and move records from the **DUMPTABLE** table to multiple different tables in **stage2**.
I do the movement in batches(transaction). So I pick a batch of let's say size 5000. If everything works I loop and select the next batch.
But if the transaction fails and all the 5000 records are rolled back. So the only choice left is to process each record in that 5000 batch and go one by one.

Btw this is the query to process from **DUMPTABLE** to one of the **stage2** tables.

```
insert into stage2.A
        (col1,col2..)
        (select
        col1,col2
    from stage1.dump
    where is_processed = False
    and batch_id = 1
    );
    insert into stage2.errors
    (failed_id)(
    select id from
     stage1.dump
    where id not in (
    select id from staging2.A) and batch_id = 1);
```

In case of failure if I go one by one. It will cost me 1 query per row(If no of the destination tables in **stage2** are 1). So 5000 queries in total.

If I move data from stage1 **DUMPTABLE** to multiple stage2 tables (let's say 10 tables). It will cost me 5000x10 = 50000 queries.
Can I do something better?
I will do processing in python with Postgres as backend if that matters.

Comment: PostgreSQL charges 0.00000 cents per query.  What is the basis of the cost you mention?  network round trip time?  fsync time? IOPS? Is this measured or simply conjecture?

Comment: Your example code should have few avenues for failure.  What are the ones you have actually seen?  Different failures yield to different solutions.

Comment: @jjanes Any kind of failure will lead to a failed transaction but the common the common one are unique violation/invalid types

Comment: @jjanes  round trips, network cost, Cannot process in parallel threads because there is only 1 record to process.

Comment: @jjanes I was thinking to reduce the size of the batch in case of failure, will break 5000 to 2500 and repeat the process. If even those fails will break to 1/2 and it goes on decreasing by half. I cannot find something concrete resource. Just random thought, dont know if it's worth the effort or not.

Comment: That's is what I did when facing similar issues (but on Oracle, not PostgreSQL) but I just went from 25000 directly to 1.  The aggravation of trying to do the binary search and losing the other work in the batch each for each halving just wasn't worth it.  Have you looked into [pgloader](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader)?

Comment: Unique key violations should be findable ahead of time with `WHERE EXISTS(...)` queries.  Data type problems can *usually* be pre-identified by regexp in whatever process brings the data into the system in the first place.

Comment: @jjanes they were just some of the issues. I can use `on conflict to do nothing` for uniqueness violation. I'm trying to be on the safe side whether there is one single solution because I cannot write solutions for all the possible failures which can happen during transactions.

Comment: @jjanes pgloader looks nice. I'll into this and if possible maybe extract something out of it, If unable to use this extension completely. Thanks for pointing this out.